# node-fetch: [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated

Tags: node.js, deprecation-warning, node-fetch

My usage is pretty basic:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
const res = await fetch(url, GenerateRequestOptions(token));
```

and the `fetch` call yields a warning:

```
[DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
```

As I'm not accessing `headers` directly, so I guess the fix should be in the package?

Comment: I got this too, but only on the occasional request, not all. Did you ever get to the bottom of it? I'm also using express 4.17.1, so I'll be looking there next.

Comment: Nope, I think it just disappeared after package upgrade.

Comment: Interesting, I’m on the latest express and latest node-fetch. There must be something else in my app sending stuff LOL.

Comment: @BenSteward did you get rid of the [DEP0066] ? Having same issue and also have latest version installed "node-fetch": "^2.6.0"

Comment: Node documentation https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options explains can have a Environment Variable NODE_OPTIONS='--trace-deprecation' but when added to my AWS Lambda no extra information was displayed :(

Comment: So sorry @Riga I think I resolved this for myself, but don't remember how, or if I even resolved it "on purpose" to be honest.

Comment: @BenSteward thanks for taking the time to reply. If something comes to mind please post it.